# Save and restore window y position in Next js / React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scroll, react-router, next.js

I'm using nextjs **Link** with shallow and replace properties to change url from `/author` to `/author?book=234523452` when the query is detected page conditionally hides an InfiniteScroll component and show a component with a single book instead.
Single book component has a "X" to go back (also wrapped within a Link) so to show again the InfiniteScrollComponent.

What I'm trying to do is save the current window Y on query (single book) and when the "X" gets clicked move to that stored position via useState.

I'd like to mention that unfortunately **scroll={false}** doesn't work for my case.

this is my page relevant code:

```
const [scrollPos, setScrollPos] = useState()

const readUrl = (url, bool) => {
  if (url){
    setScrollPos(window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop)
    setUrlNow(url)
  }else{
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', () => {
      if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
        //setTimeout(function(){
          window.scrollTo(0,scrollPos)
        //},200)
      }
    })
  }
  setToggle(bool)
  
  return
}
```

`if (url)` means it's routing from `/author` (so with InfiniteScroll component) to `/author?book=234523452` (with single book), `else` means the "X" got clicked basically and so is routing back to `/author`

The `setTimeout(function()` seems to work most of the times but not always, and also adds an ugly moving effect to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `scrollPos` for reach `retainedComponent` and there is detailed guidance [here](https://medium.com/@angus.russell89/next-js-keep-page-components-mounted-between-page-transitions-and-maintain-scroll-position-205b34539a26)

Comment: I actually made a mistake not pointing out the first page is /author/[id] , it's dynamic, and it's created via getStaticPaths at build time, which generates about 300 different [id]. Is it still possible to use the method you suggested?

Comment: I used the tutorial for my website, and it works like charm.